# Any good text editor for which I can write plugin/extensions in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, text-editor

Is there any good text editor available for which I can write plugins/extensions using nodejs? I have a node app which I run like this

```
node app.js -c fileName.js destFile.js
```

so I want whatever file I am editing, I can select some menu and the node command runs with fileName as current file.

Comment: [Atom](http://atom.io/) is built on top of Node.js, so you can write plugins for that in plain Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

look into Githubs [Atom](https://atom.io) editor. It's a very customizable text editor that uses node.js and other web technologies.

Answer (score 0):

Please try geany.
You can set build command :
- add Execute for examples, add in command : node 
And in terminal below, You can stop node with control c